C# .NET 4.8 - My Project is not being created by default in launchSettings.json
I created a new project within Visual Studio Community 2022 and the project does not exist in launchSettings.json.
It used to do this be default. However, I must have pressed a key on keyboard or click some inadvertently through a muscle twitch or flinch or something because it no longer creates be default anymore.
What setting would I change to get this to work?
Steps:
Open Visual Studio
'Create New Project'
Blank Solution - Type in name
Right click solution > Add
New Project
Type in project name BookStoreApp.API
Click Create
And... nothing in profiles...
I'm expecting the project to show in profiles with IIS Express, https, and http.
{
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5109"
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7290;http://localhost:5109"
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:50107",
      "sslPort": 44322
    }
  }
}

Just for context I did the following: System reboot Reinstall of Visual Studio System Restore of Windows > took no prisoners > all files wiped Issue still remained. Just weird to me that it would stop. I guess I can just rename the http profile to my project, but the project still should be added to the launchSettings.json file by default. –

Is your project type ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)? Could you share a screenshot of your project structure without privacy?

As far as I know and based on my testing.
The default launchSettings.json does not appear to exist in the ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) structure.
There is launchSettings.json in the ASP.NET Core Web App project.

Can you show us the default launchsettings.json

Are you trying to create blank solutions so no file is created automatically? You need to create a required file by Add option on a created solution.
You should select proper project template
like ASP.NET Core WEB API,ASP.Net Core Web App,ASP.NET Web Application.
Please follow the same step with the ASP.NET template.
